# Unable to connect MySQL Workbench to Google Cloud SQL instance

Tags: android, mysql, database, google-cloud-sql

I have been trying to connect my Google CLoud SQL instance to MySQL workbench and I get an error saying "**Unknown MySQL server host**".

Following are the parameters I used in testing the  connection.

hostname: instanceid-ipaddress of the cloud SQL instance
port: 3306
username: root
password: as provided in my instance settings

The error message: Unkown MySQL server host 'jovial-coral-544:demo-instance-173.194.241.132'(0)

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The hostname needs to be just the IP (`173.194.241.132` in your case).